# Сопоставьте, пожалуйста, неправленый и правленый фрагмент текста

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

> Смешливый, юркий, подвижный и совсем небольшого росточка, что редкость
> для тех краев. Он возник из зыбкого воздуха недалеко от входа в дом,
> на красной, каменистой почве саванны. - Меня зовут Дейди. Дейди Ноу
> Лейрана, сказал и захихикал, как будто на редкость удачно пошутил. Его
> многочисленные браслеты и украшения весело запрыгали в такт, а его
> широкое черное лицо похожее на древнюю маску эбенового дерева украсила
> белоснежная улыбка.

Требуется минимальное вмешательство: только необходимое (ибо нет предела совершенству).

Если можно оставить "похожее на древнюю маску эбенового дерева", я оставлю, но мне слышится призвук "маски дерева" (без предлога).

В остальном жду Вашего одобрения или возражений против изменённой пунктуации.

> Смешливый, юркий, подвижный и совсем небольшого росточка, что редкость
> для тех краёв, он возник из зыбкого воздуха недалеко от входа в дом,
> на красной каменистой почве саванны.
>
> – Меня зовут Дейди. Дейди Ноу
> Лейрана.
>
> Сказал и захихикал, как будто на редкость удачно пошутил. Его
> многочисленные браслеты и украшения весело запрыгали в такт, а его
> широкое чёрное лицо, похожее на древнюю маску из  эбенового дерева,
> украсила белоснежная улыбка.

Или представление Дейди лучше закавычить внутри текста?

> ...Он возник из зыбкого воздуха недалеко от входа в дом, на красной
> каменистой почве саванны. «Меня зовут Дейди. Дейди Ноу Лейрана». –
> Сказал и захихикал, как будто на редкость удачно пошутил.

Нужно ли тире после **так** оформленной прямой речи?

Comment: На мой взгляд, Галина, все у вас прекрасно.

Comment: Мне больше нравится с репликой, а не с прямой речью. Прямая речь теряется среди текста. "Похожее на древнюю маску эбенового дерева" яснее, конечно, с предлогом, но и без предлога возможно, сам текст экзотический, несколько устаревшее беспредложное сочетание смотрится нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смешливый, юркий, подвижный и совсем небольшого росточка, что редкость для тех краев. Он возник из зыбкого воздуха недалеко от входа в дом, на красной, каменистой почве саванны. **"Меня зовут Дейди. Дейди Ноу Лейрана".** Сказал и захихикал, как будто на редкость удачно пошутил. Его многочисленные браслеты и украшения весело запрыгали в такт, а его широкое черное лицо похожее на древнюю маску эбенового дерева украсила белоснежная улыбка.

**Пояснение.** Нестандартное оформление прямой речи, **слова автора как бы опущены.** Сравнить: "Меня зовут Дейди. Дейди Ноу Лейрана", ― сказал он. Сказал и захихикал, как будто на редкость удачно пошутил.